# How to send response back to client using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have `socket.emit` call from client to server in response i want to have filename to the client that is not happening with below code not sure what is implemented wrong any idea, I do not see any error. How can i get response fro server using `socket.emit` ?

client.js

```
 socket.emit('startRecording',function (response) {
            console.log('start recording emit response',response);
        });
```

server.js

```
 socket.on('startRecording',function () {
        var response;
        logsRecording(function (filename) {
            response = filename;
            return response;
            //socket.emit('filename',filename);
        });
```

Comment: `glitr-router` and `glitr-router-client` allows for response functionality from both server and connected client like you would in expressjs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To acknowledge the message, your handler for the `startRecording` event needs to accept an acknowledgement callback as a parameter. You can then call that with your desired data. See [Sending and getting data (acknowledgements)](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements)

```
socket.on('startRecording',function (socket, ackFn) {
    var response;
    logsRecording(function (filename) {
        ackFn(filename);
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could add a listener for that `filename` event you have commented out, in the client.js:

```
socket.emit('startRecording');
socket.on('filename', function(filename) {
    console.log('Filename received: ' + filename);
});
```

It might be helpful to run through [Get Started: Chat application](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) starting at the heading "Integrating Socket.IO" to get a more general understanding of Websockets.

Answer (score 7):

Your server code should look like this:

```
socket.on('startRecording',function (callbackFn) {
    var response;
    logsRecording(function (filename) {
        callbackFn(filename);
    });
```

If you want to pass in data from your client:

```
socket.emit('startRecording', {someData: 'value'}, function (response) {
```

then server will be :

```
socket.on('startRecording',function (dataFromClient, callbackFn) {
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Thank you for this helpfull hint

Here an 2020 "call" example call possible to use with moleculer microservices with four arguments:

The server responds in the callback function with two arguments err and res for the angular promise.

> Angular 9 socket io

```js
protected call(method: string, param?: any) {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.socket.emit("call", method, param, (err: any, res: unknown) => {
                console.log(res);
                if (err) { return reject(err); }
                return resolve(res);
            });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

> Socket IO server response

```js
  socket.on('call', function(method, param, callbackFn){ // call method, param, 
    console.log(param);
    switch (method) {
        case "test":
            console.log("test detected");
            callbackFn(null , {name:"test",email:"test"});          
            break;
    }
  });
```